# Is it incorrect to use ellipses when writing an irrational number's approximate value with a $\approx$?

Tags: article-writing

For example, is it incorrect to write that Euler's number is
$$
e \approx 2.718\dots
$$
or is it more proper to write
$$
e \approx 2.718
$$
or, maybe I should just write
$$
e = 2.718\dots
$$

Comment: Writing $e = 2.718 \ldots$ indicates that the first $4$ digits are exactly $2.718$, i.e. that
$2.718 \le e < 2.719$. On the other hand, if you use $\approx$ you aren't really making a precise claim that $e$ is in a certain interval;

Comment: It is correct to write $e=2.718...$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is incorrect to write $e\approx 2.718...$ as the entirety of the expansion is implied by the "$...$" after the digits. Since this *is* $e$, what you'd be saying is that $e\approx e$, which is obviously nonsense. However, $e\approx 2.718$ is perfectly fine. If you want to use an ellipsis, you need to use the equals sign.

Answer (score 0):

The only time approximately should be used is when an approximation is done. Additionally, ellipses imply continuation (literal meaning in math: "and so forth"), therefore the ellipses in $2.718...$ imply the rest of the digits in Eulers number should follow. So it would be correct to write $e \approx 2.718$ since $e$ is being approximated from $2.718281828...$ to $2.718$.